# What's the difference between -- and &~ in Scala

Tags: scala

'--' the document say: Creates a new $coll from this $coll by removing all elements of another collection.

'&~' the document say: The difference of this set and another set.

i use both of two symbol can get same result.

so is there have some difference between this two symbol? For example, there are different time complexity or memory occupation?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html).

`--` accepts any kind of `IterableOnce` whereas `&~` only accepts other `Sets`
Arguably, if you have two sets, you should prefer `&~` since it is probably optimized.